# вывести данные из mysql

Tags: php, mysql, база-данных

есть таблица 
[image: ,fpf]
как мне вывести в запросе вот в таком виде для определенного teacher

дата

- время
- время 2
- время3

дата

- время
- время 2
- время 3

Comment: SELECT ddate, GROUP_CONCAT(dtaime) FROM teachers WHERE teacher=22 GROUP BY ddate ORDER BY ddate

Comment: 2018-10-30
09:00:00,10:00:00,11:00:00,12:00:00,13:00:00,08:00
время выводит в строчку с запятой, а как потом ее обработать в шаблоне?

Comment: а в каком виде нужно, в таком и выводите. сепаратор другой?

Comment: в `group_concat()` запихайте не просто `dtaime` а `date_format(dtaime, '%H;%i')` получите только метки чч:мм. настороне пхп можете разделить его через `explode(",", ...)`. Но вообще хранение даты и времени в отдельных столбцах - сомнительная идея. А выборка данных с помощью такого агрегирования исключает добавление в выборке других столбцов.

Comment: *как мне вывести в запросе вот в таком виде* Это в принципе невозможно - набор записей ВСЕГДА плоская таблица, без каких-то там уровней. Формирование нужного вывода делают уже в PHP. По реализации: получаем записи для нужного teacher с сортировкой по дате и по времени. Результат перебираем одним циклом. В переменной храним дату предыдущей записи. Если текущая дата (запись) не равна предыдущей (переменная) - выводим сперва дату, потом время, иначе только время.

Comment: d php мне нужно вывести в select где optgroup label="Дата"><option value="time">

Answer (score -1):

Как вариант

Получаем все нужные записи

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM `table` WHERE `teacher` = 22";
```

Создадим временную переменную и перебираем каждую запись.

```
$temp = [];
foreach ($result as $item) $temp[$item['ddate']][] = $item;
```

Здесь просто выводим вложенным циклом

```
foreach ($temp as $ddate => $items) { ?>
    <div><?= $ddate ?></div>

    <ul>
        <?php foreach ($items as $item) { ?>
            <li><?= $item['dtaime'] ?></li>
        <?php } ?>
    </ul>
<?php } ?>
```